# laravel 4 cannot get phpunit testing to work

Tags: shell, testing, command-line, laravel-4, phpunit

I'v installed phpunit by adding it into my composer.js and running the update. The composer did it's thing and automatically installed phpunit and updated various scripts.

I then ran the 'phpunit' command (from the laravel folder) as instructed by the docs and received

```
 'phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
```

Which is fustrating as the doc simply say

```
You may run all of the tests for your application by executing the phpunit command from your terminal.
```

Which seem to be false.

So after looking around trying out various things I managed to get a response from

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit
```

which I ran from the same folder where phpunit.xml is located.

The response I got was

```
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../phpunit/phpunit"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/phpunit"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

What is that?? That they what I'm expected to receive from the unit testing. I assume not.
My understanding is that it will run all the unit tests located in the laravel/app/test/ folder.

What is going on and how do I get this to work?
Note I am running from the windows CMD.

Comment: Just run `vendor/bin/phpunit` by itself - dont include `php` - that should work?

Comment: I already tried that. 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: because you are on Windows, you probably need to add `vendor/bin/phpunit` to your PATH

Comment: But I'll give you a piece of advice - just download and use Homestead. Trying to use Laravel in Windows is going to give you all sorts of issues. Trust me, I used to do it as well until I switched to Homestead. Best thing I ever did: http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

Comment: Is there no other way to run it on windows.... I must mess with my path or run it from a virtual box....

Comment: There is a way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655136/install-phpunit-on-windows or http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2011/04/installing-phpunit-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried installing the laravel homestead but this just introduced more headaches and problems.

To get phpunit working I edited the 'Path' environment variable.

Method for windows 7
1) Right click on 'My computer'->properties
2) In the left hand column click 'Advanced System Settings'
3) under the Advance tab click 'Enviroment Variables'
4) Under 'System Variable' local the 'Path' variable and click edit
5) Append the location of phpunit.bat to the end of the variable data.
IE C:/some/other/thing; C:/something/else; C:/myproject/laravel/vendor/bin/
6) Save it all.

This is what I've done and it seem to work fine.