# PHPUNIT Installation

Tags: phpunit, composer-php

I am trying to install PHPUnit in my windows pc. If I execute `phpunit -version`, then I am getting output **PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.** But if I try to execute `phpunit` then I am getting below error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in D:\php7\htdocs\learn\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1046
Stack trace:
#0 D:\php7\htdocs\learn\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(167): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 D:\php7\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 D:\php7\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 D:\php7\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in D:\php7\htdocs\learn\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1046

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in D:\php7\htdocs\learn\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1046

Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in D:\php7\htdocs\learn\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1046

Call Stack:
    0.0002     345344   1. {main}() D:\php7\php\phpunit:0
    0.0036     539984   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\php7\php\phpunit:46
    0.0036     542288   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() D:\php7\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
    0.0254    2122272   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() D:\php7\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
    0.0255    2122296   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration() D:\php7\htdocs\learn\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:167
```

*Why I am getting this error ?*

Answer (score 3):

PHPUnit 3.7 has not been maintained for ~ three years. You want to have a look at [more recent](https://phpunit.de/) versions of PHPUnit.

That being said, it looks like you are experiencing what is explained [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2432).

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem and just want to add example to Sebastian's post.

My Windows 10 already has the stable version of PHPUnit-1.3.2 as indicated by 
    pear list-all

I required version useful for php-5.3.28, pear-1.9.5 and zend-2.3.0.

Following the Instructions for Windows on, 
    https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html 
using C:\bin with phpunit-4.1.5.phar in the phpunit.cmd file with a PATH environment variable runs the PHPUnit from command line.

Kindly note, one needs phpunit-4.1.* as indicated when you use Composer
[Install phpunit on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655136/install-phpunit-on-windows) 
In present case both work using Composer as well as C:\bin alternative.